# Как сделать отправку запроса после формирования товара Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

есть API которая отправляет СМС. Тестировали вчера через Isomnia все хорошо работает( на JS ), есть интернет магазин. После формирования товара надо отправить http запрос с нужными параметрами. Каким образом можно сделать на php такое. Я предполагаю что в functions.php поставить функцию что при успешном формирование заказа, отправляет http запрос. Но какая функция в WC отвечает за выполнение после успешного формирования заказа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать хуки [woocommerce_order_status_(to)](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_order_status_(to)) . Где (to) - этот статус заказа. Событие срабатывает на изменение статуса заказа

Например, отработка статуса proccesing

```
function send_order($order_id) {
        
        $order = new \WC_Order( $order_id );

        // отправляем sms

        // $order->get_billing_phone()
        // $order->get_billing_first_name()
        // $order_items  = $order->get_items( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_purchase_order_item_types', 'line_item' ) );
}
 
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'send_order', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Для выполнено status_completed?

Comment: @Dan add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_paying_customer' );